# Testing Websites on Phone

Tags: applications

I was wondering is there any way to test websites on my phone? I am a Web Programmer, and I usually code designs which are responsive. So I want to check if the design is compatible on mobile phone. I use XAMPP on my Windows 7 Laptop for Apache services. Is there anything like Hamachi I could use to see my `http://localhost` via my Phone?

Comment: If your phone is on the same Wi-Fi network as your laptop, you don't need Hamachi or anything like that. Just set up your development web server to accept connections from the same network. This isn't really an Android question.

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: See the last sentence of Dan's comment: *This isn't really an Android question.* Hint: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) might be a good address for that. You might also wish to check with [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look: [Chrome DevTools for Mobile: Emulate and Screencast](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/12/chrome-devtools-for-mobile-emulate-and.html)

Comment: Some what correct but can't seem to find the download link for the dev tool.

Answer (score -1):

You can use automated testing over a wide range of devices ...
using 
http://mite.keynote.com/

refer this it may help u ...
http://mite.keynote.com/how-it-works/index.php

Comment: 75 MB is a lot dude. My code editor is hardly 2 MB man. Plus I want to see a live view of how does it look like on various mobile phones.

Comment: look at this link it may help you ...I have a List of a Few things that Can be used instead of Hamachi which you might find handy



Http://www.tunggle.com

http://www.comodo.com/home/email-security/vpn-access.php

http://openvpn.net/

http://www.wippien.com/